# Vedaldi‘s SIFT in MATLAB - error in sift_compile

Tags: matlab, mex, sift

When I tried to compile Vedaldi's SIFT algorithm in MATLAB, I got the following error while compiling:
sift_compile

```
D:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2010A~1\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: 'imsmooth.c' not found. 

??? Error using ==> mex at 222
Unable to complete successfully.

Error in ==> sift_compile at 33
mex('imsmooth.c',opts{:}) ;
```

I did got mex to run on other cases, the compiler I used is VS2008. And the path of the imsmooth.c and other source code is also included in the MATLAB path. Could someone give me some hints how should I get it work?

Comment: Try using the full path of imsmooth.c.  Do you actually have any important options in opts?  Also while I was experimenting with mex, I couldn't compile using the parentheses as you did there.  Instead try `mex imsmooth.c -options`  That might work out better for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011a\sift\

add in the pathnames helps!